# whether to import "parallel" package in R when using foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

I am using `foreach()` function in the `foreach` R package for parallel computing. Besides that function, I think it is also required to use `registerDoMC()` function in the `doMC` package.

However, when I write my `DESCRIPTION` file, the `Imports` section contains `doMC (>= 1.3.0), foreach (>= 1.4.1)`, but when I run my code, an error indicates: **cannot find the `iter` function**. Thus, I also `import` the `iterators` package.

It seems that there is still error: the `mclapply()` function is to be used by `foreach()`, and this function appears in **both** the `parallel` and the `multicore` package. I include both packages in the `Imports` section, but when I run `search()`, the warnings show up:

```
Warning messages:
1: replacing previous import ‘mclapply’ when loading ‘parallel’ 
2: replacing previous import ‘mcparallel’ when loading ‘parallel’ 
3: replacing previous import ‘pvec’ when loading ‘parallel’
```

This is pretty weird: even though I explicitly `imports` both packages of `iterators` and `multicore`, I still cannot use their functions after loading my own package... Instead, I have to explicitly run:

```
library(iterators)
library(multicore)
```

in order to use my own function in my package which makes use of parallel computing. Is there anything wrong in my package writing? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify your DESCRIPTION file by adding `doMC` to the "Depends", then the "cannot find the iter function" error should go away, and functions from `foreach`, `iterators` and `doMC` will be available when your package is loaded, which seems to be your preference.  The first chapter of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) discusses the differences between "Imports" and "Depends".  Generally, it's preferable to use "Imports" to avoid forcing users of your package to load packages that are only needed within a package, but it has uses.

Actually, the "cannot find the iter function" error that you saw is caused by a bug in the `doMC` package, and using "Depends" rather than "Imports" works around this bug.  Your package should only have to import packages that it directly uses, so if you don't explicitly call `iter` or `mclapply`, you shouldn't have to import `iterators`, `parallel`, or `multicore`.  And since `parallel` has subsumed `multicore`, you should never import both `parallel` and `multicore`, which should avoid the warning messages that you saw.

I submitted a fix for the `doMC` bug to the package maintainer, so you should be able to import `foreach` and `doMC` into packages without an error in the next version of the package.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! Yes, it indeed works if I put doMC in the Depends section ;-)